# I am getting undefined while trying to pass array to a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to ReactJS and i am having issues with passing an array from one class to another class

Here is my Syntax:

```
class Application extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }  
  method_one(){
    var array = ["one","two"]
    this.state =array
  }
  render() {
    return(

    <div>{this.method_one()}

        {console.log(this.state.data)}
        <AppTwo content={this.state.data}/>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
class AppTwo extends React.Component{
  render(){

    return<div> {console.log(this.props.content)}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />,document.getElementById("main"))
```

The console.log() returns undefined.
Can you help me figure out what I am missing?

Comment: I just fixed the type but I am still facing the same issue

Comment: `this.setState({ data: array })`.

Comment: for some reason this.setState({data:array}) is looping. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @AvaLucas read react lifecycle, any thing in render will be called for infinite times.

Comment: Add this at the end of AppTwo component and try it.

`AppTwo.propTypes = {
  content: React.PropTypes.array
};`

Comment: Inside your `method_one`, you're setting state wrong. Only in your constructor should you use `this.state = {}`. Inside your function, write `this.setState({ data: array })`. Your app is looping because everytime you modify state, it calls `render()`. You're editing state in the `render` function (see `<div>{this.method_one()}`). Hence the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that yo try to mutate state of component and the loop happens because you call method constantly.
Try this code:

```
class Application extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
   data: []
  }

  this.method_one = this.method_one.bind(this); //get class context to this method
 }  
 method_one(){
  var array = ["one","two"]
  this.setState({ data: array });
 }
 render() {
  return(
   <div onClick={this.method_one}> //do not call this metod constantly you just need to indicate it

    {console.log(this.state.data)}
    <AppTwo content={this.state.data}/>
   </div>

  )
 }
}

class AppTwo extends React.Component{
 render(){

  return<div> {console.log(this.props.content)}</div>
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />,document.getElementById("main"))
```

Sorry for my English:) Hope its help you.